How to get a list of manually modified values of a column from a Pivot Table?
I cannot find an answer to my problem anywhere. Sometimes, by mistake, when I press the spacebar, a value in my pivot table gets replaced with empty. Once I realize this has happened, I can't determine which value was there previously, nor can I find a list of previous values compared to the current manually modified value.
Example ( this is an example table on which I will substitute the Value Tokyo for " ").

In the new table Tokyo appears as:

Even if I press update on the table, the value Tokyo won't come back and will remain blank.
What I'm looking for is somewhere I can find all the values modified and the new values.

If you activate any cell in the pivot table, this macro will reset all pivot items if the city field to their original values:
Sub ResetFieldItemNames()
    Dim itm As PivotItem
    For Each itm In ActiveCell.PivotTable.PivotFields("city").PivotItems
        If itm.SourceName <> itm.Name Then
            itm.Name = itm.SourceName
        End If
    Next
End Sub


Good and easy solution! Thanks,

ALT-5 will refresh your data, also check the source data to make certain this is pulling the correct range(s) and make sure those cells have only characters and not some sort of conditional formatting.

This didn't solve the problem, I press ALT+5 and didn't change the values.
